# Problems with buck converter

Tags: power-electronics, buck, texas-instruments

I designed a PCB with two [LM61495](https://www.ti.com/product/LM61495) buck converters. They should produce a 3V3 and 5V output. However, for both circuits, the output is 12V. The picture below shows the output of one of the channels measured. All voltages measured are 1/10 of the actual voltages.

[image]

Given that I have two circuits with the exact same error, I rule out an manufacturing error. The schematics of the two circuits can be seen below.

[image]

[image]

I am not able to detect an error in those schematics that could explain the output. As far as I can see, the circuit is exactly like the example in the datasheet.

Do you have an idea what the problem could be? The waveform looks a bit suspicious to me (not a normal ripple) but I can not deduce an error from this.

Comment: Is it switching?

Comment: Why did you rule out a manufacturing error? Did you verify there is none? For example, I have been bitten by manufacturing error. The feedback resistor that was mounted had ohms instead of kilo-ohms it read in the BOM, so the prototype burned up with overvoltage, because I did not verify the feedback resistors before applying power. Lesson learnt never to trust anything unless verified by  measurements before applying power.

Comment: @bobflux how can I measure whether it's switching? I assumed it is switching given the ripple but I now realize that this conclusion is wrong and the ripple might come from the input voltage.

Comment: @Justme I ruled out an manufacturing error due to the problem appearing twice. But you are right, this reasoning is wrong. I'll try to measure/verify all the values.

Comment: @bobflux Looking at the output waveform again, the rippfle frequency does not match the expected 400kHz of the buck converter. So it might not be switching

Comment: To know if it is switching you can probe SW node with your scope. You should see a rectangular waveform from 0V to input voltage. Note you can set your scope so it displays the correct voltage instead of x10, there's a menu to tell the scope you have a 1:10 probe connected. Can you show the layout?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this can be but, the device in your schematic has 20 pins whereas the device in the data sheet you linked has 16 pins like this: -

[image]

I'll leave it to you to figure out reasons why. Your schematic: -

[image]

There are only 16 pins: -

[image]

Comment: The OP;s schematic symbol (and presumably PCB footprint) has an extra pin for each of the corner pads on the package which appear larger than all the others.

Comment: exactly @brhans. I verified the footprint and it is correct. The additional pins are in the corner.

Comment: @mlx11 count the pins on the 1st image and there are 16. There are only 16 pins and that image is from the data sheet link in the question. I've added another image.

Comment: @Andy the footprint is correct. It models each corner pad as 2 pads (for whatever reason). So the VCC pad is VCC_1 and VCC_2 which model the same pad.